# Why does't the \SetAlFnt work in the algorithm2e?

Tags: fonts, fontsize, algorithm2e

I want to use the `\SetAlFn` to change the font size of the algorithm, but it doesn't seem work at all. Here is my code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[tight,TABTOPCAP]{subfigure}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[noline]{algorithm2e}
\SetAlFnt{\small}
\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.8\linewidth}%
        \begin{algorithm}[H]%
            \DontPrintSemicolon
            \SetNoFillComment
            \SetAlFnt{\small\sf}
            %\SetCommentSty{tiny}
            \SetKwProg{Fn}{Function}{}{end}
            \Fn{$u^h \leftarrow $V-cycle($A_h, u_0^h, f_h$)}{
                \uIf{$h==h_0$}{\KwRet{$u_h \leftarrow A_h^{-1}f_h $}\tcc*[r]{bottom solve}}
                $u^h \leftarrow \text{smooth}(A_h,u_0^h,f_h)$\tcc*[r]{pre-smooth}
                $r^h \leftarrow f_h-A_hu^h$\tcc*[r]{residual}
                $r^{2h} \leftarrow I_h^{2h}r^h$\tcc*[r]{restriction}
                $\delta^{2h} \leftarrow \text{V-cycle}(A_{2h},0,r^{2h})$\tcc*[r]{recursive call}
                $u^h \leftarrow u^h + I_{2h}^h\delta^{2h}$\tcc*[r]{interpolation}
                $u^h \leftarrow \text{smooth}(A_{2h},u^h,f_h)$\tcc*[r]{post-smooth}
                \KwRet{$u^h$}\;
            }   
            \caption{V-cycle}   
        \end{algorithm}%
    \end{minipage}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `\SetAlFnt{\small\sf}` command must occur before the `\begin{algorithm}` environment.  Also the difference may not be very obvious as you already have a `\SetAlFnt{\small}` before the environment.  Try moving it and just to test make the font size `\Large`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Styling of document elements should preferably be done in a consistent manner. As such and rightly so, [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e)'s `\SetAlFnt` is issued at the start of the `algorithm` environment. That's why, when you call `\SetAlFnt` halfway through the algorithm... or even immediately after `\begin{algorithm}`, it's too late to change the algorithm fonts.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[noline]{algorithm2e}
\SetAlFnt{\small\sffamily}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \DontPrintSemicolon
  \SetNoFillComment
  \SetKwProg{Fn}{Function}{}{end}
  \Fn{$u^h \leftarrow {}$\textup{\AlFnt V-cycle}($A_h, u_0^h, f_h$)}{
    \uIf{$h==h_0$}{\KwRet{$u_h \leftarrow A_h^{-1}f_h $}\tcc*[r]{bottom solve}}
    $u^h \leftarrow \text{smooth}(A_h,u_0^h,f_h)$\tcc*[r]{pre-smooth}
    $r^h \leftarrow f_h-A_hu^h$\tcc*[r]{residual}
    $r^{2h} \leftarrow I_h^{2h}r^h$\tcc*[r]{restriction}
    $\delta^{2h} \leftarrow \text{V-cycle}(A_{2h},0,r^{2h})$\tcc*[r]{recursive call}
    $u^h \leftarrow u^h + I_{2h}^h\delta^{2h}$\tcc*[r]{interpolation}
    $u^h \leftarrow \text{smooth}(A_{2h},u^h,f_h)$\tcc*[r]{post-smooth}
    \KwRet{$u^h$}\;
  }
  \caption{V-cycle}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Note how only certain elements conform to the newly set serif font. That is because while `\AlFnt` (defines based on `\SetAlFont`) is issued at `\begin{algorithm}`, each component has their own set of font definitions (like `\SetKwSty` for `K`ey`w`ords, etc.). For more details, see section **9.5.3 Setting font standard font shapes and styles** (p 27) of the [`algorithm2e` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf).